# White background class in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm searching for a class that makes the element a white background.

maybe something like .bg-white, I couldn't find it in Bootstrap but maybe its hidden somewhere?

Comment: from what I know there no class for this. Just do it yourself.

Comment: The only colours defined in Bootstrap are for `.warning`, `.success`, `.danger` etc

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 4, Bootstrap does have white, light and dark background classes.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bg-light text-dark">Light background</div>
<div class="bg-dark text-white">Dark background</div>
<div class="bg-white text-dark">White background</div>
```

Source : [Background Color - Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color)

Answer (score 14):

Bootstrap doesn't have a white background class.

Create your own:

```
.white-bg{
    background:#ffffff !important;
}
```

This can be placed in `bootstrap.css` or your own custom stylesheet if you've created one.

The only backgrounds there are in bootstrap are:

```
.bg-primary
.bg-success
.bg-info
.bg-warning
.bg-danger
```

Source: [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-backgrounds)

Comment: make sure you have at least bootstrap version 3.1.0, that's when these classes were added. Won't work for earlier versions of bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any style in bootstrap only for white-background. So apply yourself.

Add a class   `bg-white` to your html element. Then in apply the `background` style.

```
.bg-white{
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

Example

```
<div class="bg-white">      
  <!-- div contents go here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to define such class yourself. Put the following in your custom CSS file.

**CSS:**

```
.bg-white {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

In Bootstrap you have the following pre-defined backgrounds:

Bootstrap 3.1.0:

```
<div class="bg-primary">...</div>
<div class="bg-success">...</div>
<div class="bg-info">...</div>
<div class="bg-warning">...</div>
<div class="bg-danger">...</div>
```

Bootstrap 3.0.3:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">...</div>
<div class="alert alert-info">...</div>
<div class="alert alert-warning">...</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger">...</div>
```